# How to stop django-html formatting to one line with tags

Tags: html, django, templates, tags, autoformatting

When I save my django-html file the following changes occur in auto formatting.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% if dice %} {% for die in dice
%}
<img src="{{die.image.url}}" alt="{{die.name}}" />
{% endfor %} {% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

I want to have something like the following instead...

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if dice %}
  {% for die in dice %}
    <img src="{{die.image.url}}" alt="{{die.name}}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have Beautify installed and my settings are as follows...

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "django-html": "html"
  },

"files.associations": {
    "**/*.html": "html",
    "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
    "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
    "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
  },
  "beautify.language": {
    "html": ["htm", "html", "django-html"]
  },
```